# Triggering for events

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a queue definition like below:

```
DEFINE QLOCAL(TRIG.QLOCAL) + 
       DESCR('Example Queue for Triggering') + 
       DEFPRTY(0) + 
       DEFSOPT(SHARED) + 
       GET(ENABLED) + 
       MAXDEPTH(5000) + 
       MAXMSGL(4194304) + 
       MSGDLVSQ(PRIORITY) + 
       PUT(ENABLED) + 
       QDEPTHHI(80) +
       QDPHIEV(ENABLED)+
       RETINTVL(999999999) + 
       TRIGTYPE(EVERY) + 
       PROCESS(TRIG.PROCESS) + 
       INITQ(TRIG.INITQ) + 
       USAGE(NORMAL) + 
       REPLACE
```

I have defined the process like below:

```
DEFINE PROCESS(TRIG.PROCESS) APPLTYPE(UNIX) +
       APPLICID(/appn/sy31/QdepthHiAlert.sh) +
       ENVRDATA(' ') +
       USERDATA(' ') 
       DESCR('PROCESS FOR TESTING QDEPTH HIGH EVENT') +
       REPLACE
```

I have a trigger monitor running as service like below:

```
   SERVICE(TRIGGER_MONITOR)                STATUS(RUNNING)
   PID(49610840)                           SERVTYPE(SERVER)
   CONTROL(QMGR)                           STARTCMD(/usr/bin/runmqtrm)
   STARTARG(-m PACOHB20 -q SYSTEM.DEFAULT.INITIATION.QUEUE)
```

Here are my questions:

1. I thought, all the trigger messages will be processed by trigger monitor script. If we don't configure it on the `INITQ`, process which is associated with the queue will not run. Is that correct?
2. If Yes, Our trigger monitor is not running on the queue's `INITQ(TRIG.INITQ)`.  Must we run the trigger monitor on the `INITQ` too?
3. When we are configuring the transmission queues for triggering, we have defined the trigger data and process definitions. Though we didn't configure the trigger monitor on the initiation queue, the channel is started since we have  `runmqchi` on the `system.channel.initiation.queue`. So `runmqtrm` and `runmqchi` function similarly?
4. In here, we have the triggering for EVERY message and queue depth high event. In both the cases, trigger message will be placed to the same `INITQ`. So, how do we know what kind of alert we are receiving?

Answer (score 6):

OK, let's take these one at a time.

> I thought, all the trigger messages will be processed by trigger
>   monitor script. If we don't configure it on the INITQ, process which
>   is associated with the queue will not run. Is that correct?

If I understand what you are asking, it is whether the process is fired if there's nothing listening on the initiation queue.  That is correct.  The application queue must have `TRIGGER` set and specify the `INITQ` value.  The specified initiation queue must have an open input handle in order for MQ to format and place the trigger message.

> If Yes, Our trigger monitor is not running on the INITQ : TRIG.INITQ.
>   do we must run the trigger monitoring on the INITQ too?

Yes.  The queue's `INITQ` is where the QMgr will place any trigger messages.  The QMgr will not place the trigger messages *unless* there is an open input handle on that initiation queue, and that handle had better be from a trigger monitor it it won't work.

> When we are configuring the transmission queues, for triggering, we
>   have defined the trigger data and process definitions. Though we
>   didn't configure the trigger monitor on the initiation queue, channel
>   got run since we have runmqchi on the INITQ. So runmqtrm and runmqchi
>   function similarly?

The channel initiator is a LOT more forgiving of sloppy configuration than is the trigger monitor.  It's easy to work out from the channel definition which transmission queue it uses.  So MQ figures that if the administrator defined a queue of type `XMITQ` set it to `TRIGGER` then the intent must be to start a channel.  It then works backward from the channel defs to discover *which* channel is associated with that queue.

But there are no such safe assumptions with `runmqtrm`.  You *must* connect the dots from the queue's `INITQ` and `PROCESS` attributes to the trigger monitor listening on the specified `INITQ` and the associated process starting, correctly reading the trigger message, and then processing the queue as intended.

> In here, we have the triggering for EVERY message and queue depth high
>   event.  In both the cases, trigger message will be placed to the same
>   INITQ. So, how do we know what kind of alert we are receiving?

These are two different things.  Only one type of triggering can be specified on a queue and it is one of `FIRST`, `DEPTH`, or `EVERY`.  You can also specify that the QMgr will emit an event message to an event queue (not an initiation queue) when the queue depth exceeds some threshold.

The two things are related but completely different types of instrumentation.  The triggering instrumentation is designed to start processes under certain conditions.  The queue depth events are designed to feed real-time operational information to monitoring agents listening on the event queues.

---

For more about triggering, including a mini-tutorial built around a useful application and sample scripts to implement it, please see [*Mission:Messaging: Easing administration and debugging with circular queues*](http://ibm.co/huFW3R)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. two more queries got strike in my mind after reading this.  1. `runmqchi` works backward? Every trigger message will have have the name of the queue that caused triggering and process need to be invoked in it's payload, right? If so, why do it needs to backtrack it?

2. For queue with trigger type `DEPTH`. When `CURDEPTH` cross 80% of `MAXDEPTH`, it will generate `queue_depth_high` event. If the queue got full, will it generate `queue_depth_high` or `queue_full` event? If it generates `queue_full` event, how can we differentiate high_depth and full events?

Comment: "how can we differentiate high_depth and full events?" The Reason Code in MQCFH will be 2224 for a QDepth High event and 2053 for a QFull event.  Please see: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.doc/q049650_.htm?lang=en

Comment: The channel initiator doesn't require a process to be defined anymore, nor does it require the channel name in the queue's `PROCESS` attribute as it used to.  When the XmitQ is triggered, `runmqchi` has to figure out which channel to start by matching the `XMITQ` value specified in the channels to the name of the queue that was triggered.  However, it was easier for IBM to make `runmqchi` do this than to impose strict requirements for customers to define processes and they get fewer PMRs this way.

Comment: "Thanks for the detailed explanation."  Level of detail reflects that it was a 4-Part question. I had no choice. ;-)  (But you are welcome!)